# Is there a way to execute a php script outside Wordpress?

Tags: database, users

I need to create a script to remove some users from a WordPress DB. I would like to be able to remove those users without modify directly the database and just executing the script.

I would like to know if WordPress has a some kind of SDK or something to do this thinks without need to create a plugin.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of ways to do this.

You could use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/delete/), [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/) or even include `wp-load.php` from a custom script and use built-in `wp_delete_user()` function.